# Holding data between onclick() event of Submit Button and Form Submission from View

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Form below is posted from view to action method. `onclick()` event invokes `jquery.ajax` and passes data(content of the first `div`) to the same action method. `jquery.ajax` is executed first and form submission comes next. How can I have the value of pid (passed by jquery.ajax) when the form submitted? I need to use sth like Session, don't I?

View:

```
<form id="newform" action="/ad/newad" method="post">
    <div id="divAjax">
       <p align="center" style="background: white; margin: 0cm 0cm 0pt;">Dan</p>
       <p align="center" style="background: white; margin: 0cm 0cm 0pt;">
       <b><span contenteditable="true"> CLICK TO CHANGE</span></b>
       </p>
    </div>
    <div class=" content">
       <input type="text" name="PName"/>
       <input type="text" name="SName"/>
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit" onclick="return updatePerson();" />
    </div>
</form>
<script>
function updatePerson(){
   $.ajax({
       url         : "/ad/newad",
       type        : "POST",
       dataType    : "json",
       contentType : "application/json;",
       data        : "{ pid:'" + $("#divAjax").html() + "' }"       
   });
</script>
```

Action Method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ViewException]
[UserFilter(OpUserAuthType.Admin, OpUserAuthType.Normal)]
public ActionResult NewAd(string id, string pid, AdDetail model)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: do you want to send the html content?

Comment: I do indeed. But I am not able to send it through form submission. Thats the why I went for ajax.post for it

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to not have a submit button - just a regular button. Your form submits to the same action as your ajax post anyway.  I think maybe you just need to post all of your data at once in the click handler, not just your pid and you might not need the submit I think.

You can then use the success: or error: handler of the ajax call if you need to do something after the post has been made.

Comment: Sending a class of 70 fields. I just put a few of them. Html content is the problem to send. I am trying to do the opposite you said. But how to send the div content with form submit?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean, but I don't think you can send your html data with the submit because it's not a form input element. Therefore you could maybe add a hidden form element, and in your onclick function, populate this hidden value with the html.  Then the html should submit.